# Top bar visible in iPhone5 but not in iPhone6

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running my code on simulator iPhone5 and iPhone6. The problem is top bar is visible in iPhone5 but not in iPhone6 or iPhone6+. Please see attahced images.

[image]

and

[image]

What could be the issue?

Following steps i have performed to set top navigation color

1. few changes made in info section 
   [image]
2. following code i have added in my app delegate file

   navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
       [navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
       [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
       [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]]];

Comment: Can you check if the top bar is visible on a white background? Also are they both running the same version of iOS?

Comment: @KakshilShah Yes, top bar is visible with white background. iOS Version is same for both running

Comment: So the problem is that, in iPhone 5 it shows white top bar, and iPhone 6 it shows black? Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in info.plist.

Call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

In application did finish launching method.

And remove everything else.